# error about libpl (shared) when using pyswip (mac)

Tags: python, swi-prolog

I got the error `libpl (shared) not found.`(see below for details) when using pyswip (mac). I know there is a question about it posted several years ago, but it is not solved. I installed swiprolog(>7.0.0) with homebrew and run 2to3 for pyswip. Help me.

PS: I am learning logic programming, I need it.

> libpl (shared) not found. Possible reasons: 1) SWI-Prolog not
>   installed as a shared library. Install SWI-Prolog (5.6.34 works just
>   fine) An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

The error is thrown here.

```
# UNIX-like
try:
    _lib = CDLL("libpl.dylib")
except IndexError:
    # let's try the cwd
    _lib = CDLL("./libpl.so")
```

Comment: You can use [the online editor](https://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/simple_crossword.pl) in case you're desperate, but did you properly install it and set aliases to where it could be found or use the fully qualified path to the library's on-disk location directly in the library call? Everything in prolog is a byte stream, so if the location is incorrect it will be unable to load the files necessary.

Comment: @G_V I think it is ok. [~] where swipl                                                       20:24:40
/usr/local/bin/swipl.

Comment: Well no, the error says it can't find the files in the current location it is looking, so the question is where is it looking right now and how do we get it to find the installation correctly. Can you post the traceback?

Comment: @G_V there is no file named libpl.so or libpl.dylib. I found the file libswipl.dylib with a similar name, and copied it to the path of pyswip. but it failed. (change the corresponding path name.)

Comment: Right, but the traceback should specify a location and a filename of what it expects to find and where. You can then enter that filename into a search engine and hopefully find specific mac instructions on what to do with that file to get it to work.

Comment: @G_V I am desperate indeed. I call CDLL('/usr/local/Cellar/swi-prolog/7.6.4/libexec/lib/swipl-7.6.4/lib/libswipl.dylib', RTLD_GLOBAL) directly, and get OSError: dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/swi-prolog/7.6.4/libexec/lib/swipl-7.6.4/lib/libswipl.dylib, 10): image not found

Comment: Well, does the directory `/usr/local/Cellar/swi-prolog/7.6.4/libexec/lib/swipl-7.6.4/lib` exist? Does it contain a file called `libswipl.dylib`?

Comment: @IsabelleNewbie No, I copied a wrong directory. I call CDLL successfully now, thank you for your reminding.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a solution: pyswip does not support SWI-Prolog 8.x.x and the only SWI-Prolog version that has worked for me is Homebrew's swi-prolog 7.6.4 (latest 7.x.x stable release). Because Homebrew does not keep track of different versions of swi-prolog, I had to really dig to find the old 7.6.4 "formula". Now it works with the current version of pyswip (0.2.8).

TL; DR: Remove your current SWI-Prolog install (and remove any associated PATH editing), do `brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/09a94009142a6265b0b8e322463100610aeda964/Formula/swi-prolog.rb` and call it a day.

**EDIT**:

Caveat: This approach will not let you use some Prolog packages such as `library(process)` and `library(http/json)`. To correct this, you can install the macOS app and manually install and relink the `libncurses.6.dylib` in order for PySwip to be able to find it, like this:

```sh
brew install ncurses # Specifically install this library
sudo find / -name "libncurses.6.dylib" # You'll see an entry in /usr/local/Cellar/ncurses/6.1/lib/libncurses.6.dylib or something like that in /.../Cellar/ncurses/ (Homebrew folder)

# Now go relink the libswipl.dylib to depend on the newly installed `ncurses` library
cd /Applications/SWI-Prolog.app/Contents/swipl/lib/x86_64-darwin15.6.0 # The "darwin" version may vary depending on your OS/SWI-Prolog version

# You'll see that it is linked against a fake /opt/local/lib/libncurses.6.dylib which doesn't in fact exist
otool -L libncurses.6.dylib

# Now check the top-level lib, libswipl.dylib, it should show a "@executable_path/../swipl/lib/x86_64-darwin15.6.0/libncurses.6.dylib" or something like that depending on your version.
otool -L libswipl.dylib

# Now replace the fake with the real by actually modifying the top-level lib, libswipl.dylib. Contrary to intuition, the way linking works in macOS is that you can only modify the depending library, so libswipl.dylib instead of libncurses.6.dylib.
install_name_tool -change @executable_path/../swipl/lib/x86_64-darwin15.6.0/libncurses.6.dylib /usr/local/Cellar/ncurses/6.1/lib/libncurses.6.dylib libswipl.dylib

# Now you'll see that libswipl.dylib has been successfully modified:
otool -L libswipl.dylib
```